# Using WebMatrix.Data in Visual Studio with the facebook helpers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix

I installed the facebook helper package in my Visual Studio 2010 MVC project. Using it currently breaks my site because it can't find the classes it uses from the WebMatrix.Data and WebMatrix.WebData libraries. I can use them in my cs files, but from the facebook.cshtml file they appear to be inaccessible.

Has anybody encountered this? I know this all beta but still.

Thanx
Rinze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  the solution to this is copying the files to the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the dll files to your site bin folder, which are in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies

on my pc

Answer (score 1):

Syg, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687438/asp-net-mvc-3-issues-with-microsoft-web-helpers-v1-1/4691040#4691040) on the similar question "[ASP.NET MVC 3 - Issues with microsoft-web-helpers v1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687438/asp-net-mvc-3-issues-with-microsoft-web-helpers-v1-1)".