# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Issues with microsoft-web-helpers v1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, nuget-package

I upgraded my microsof-web-helpers package from nuget and it itself depends on facebook and twitter APIs. Now when my app attempts to run I get the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SimpleMembershipProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Source Error:


Line 216:    }
Line 217:    
Line 218:    private static SimpleMembershipProvider GetMembershipProvider() {
Line 219:        var provider = Membership.Provider as SimpleMembershipProvider;
Line 220:

Source File: c:\Users\jp\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\myproj\myproj\App_Code\Facebook.cshtml    Line: 218
```

I was wondering if anyone has come across this issue and can tell me if I need to add any additional references to my project or, worse, create a dummy SimpleMembershipProvider in my app. I am hesitant to update the facebook code because, anytime I get the latest microsoft-web-helpers from nuget i'll be forced to maintain this file.

Thanks

JP

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have the same problem.

After some googling I've found simple solution for this issue. As described [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1633879/4215379.aspx), all you need is just copy the WebMatrix.Data.dll and WebMatrix.WebData.dll files to your bin directory.

But I suggest to add references to WebMatrix.Data.dll and WebMatrix.WebData.dll to the project (and set "Copy Local" property to true for them). Then these files will be copied to the bin directory always after build, even if you remove the bin directory (which is preferred if you use version control).

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat. Though I HATE having to add bloat to my project like this. Hopefully as things mature this won't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks this just helped me out as well. I wish NuGet would do this automatically, when adding any WebMatrix packages to an MVC site.